# Django Admin Limiting results based on URL

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm working a conference registration page. The system can allow multiple conferences to be registered for and used.

I'm using the admin to manage the conferences, but I need a way in the admin system to view only the people registered for a given conference. I know I can use list filters, but I was wondering if I can somehow use the URL.

For example, is it possible to do something like this? /admin/appname/modelname/SomeConference and only have that show the instances of that model associated with that confernece?

Answer (score 0):

This is what filters are specifically for.

If you look at what happens when you activate a filter in the Admin, it just updates the URI to include a lookup value:

http://example.com/admin/core/model/?model_id__exact=1

So "technically", yes, there's a way to do this just using a URL.

Because that's how filters work in the first place.